# How to repartition spark dataframe into smaller partitions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which is partitioned by date.
In normal processing, I am processing a week of data at a time, so this means I have 7 partitions. I would like to increase this number of partitions, but without having to shuffle data or have a mix of dates in the same partition.

I've tried using `df.repartition(20, my_date_column)`, but this just results in 13 empty partitions since the hash partitioner will only get 7 distinct values.

I've also tried using `df.repartition(20, my_date_column, unique_id)`, which does increase the number of partitions to 20, but it means that dates are mixed within the partitions.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: Maybe... Take that unique_id and make some small calculation so that it would become 1 or 2 or 3. I mean 3 different values. Then you could partition on this too which would make probably 21 partitions. Just an idea. I'm just learning these things

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can increase the number of partitions by setting `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` to a smaller value. According to the [tuning guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html#other-configuration-options):

> Property Name:     **spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes**
> Default:  134217728 (128 MB)
> Meaning:  The maximum number of bytes to pack into a single partition when reading files.
> This configuration is effective only when using file-based sources
> such as Parquet, JSON and ORC.
> Since Version: 2.0.0

Alternatively, you can try `spark.sql.files.minPartitionNum` but it only means to suggest, not guarantee, the number of partitions.